# How to force ListView.builder to refresh when adding/deleting items in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

I know that I can use `this.setState()` on the parent Stateful Widget screen containing the `ListView.builder` to make the ListView rebuild its list.

The problem is I use another child stateful widget to build each of the ListView item. And Flutter documentation said that the tree build will stop whenever it encounters the same widget. This makes the ListView content does not rebuild.

How can I force ListView to "invalidate" all of its children and force rebuild the whole content, without specifying things like keys (global keys/local keys)?

EDIT: the simplified code.

```
class PostList extends extends StatefulWidget {
    final UserModel user;
    PostList({ this.user }): super();
    @override
      _PostListState createState() => _PostListState();
}

class _PostListState extends State<PostList> {
    UserModel _user;
    List<PostModel> _posts;
    final _repository = Repository();

    @override
    void initState() {
      _user = widget.user;
      _repository.fetchPosts(userId: user.id)
        .then((response) => this.setState(() => _posts = response)
        .catchError((onError) => debugPrint(onError);
    }

    addNewRandomPost() {
      final newPost = PostModel(text: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());
      this.setState(() => _posts = [newPost]..addAll(_posts ?? []));
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: "Post list"),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: (_posts?.length ?? 0) + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == 0) 
              return RaisedButton(child: Text("Add new random post"), onPressed: addNewRandomPost);
            else if(_posts == null) 
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            else 
              return PostCard(post: _posts[index - 1]);
          }
        )
    }
}

class PostCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final PostModel post;
  PostCard ({ this.post }): super();
  @override
  _PostCardState createState() => _PostCardState();
}

class _PostCardState extends State<PostCard> {
  PostModel _post;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _post = widget.post;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Card(child: 
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text(_post.text));
}
```

There's obviously more code and purpose to the `PostCard` widget that I purposely make it as Stateful widget instead of Stateless. But I just simplified it here to show that even with this simple code, whenever the "Add new random post" is tapped:

- whenever there's originally no post, the list transforms from just displaying circular indicator into correctly display the new post.
- but whenever there's already a new post there (the `_posts` is not null), if I add new post at the beginning of the list, the existing post card that already created is not changing. It only adds new post card widget at the bottom of the list showing the last post on the list which ironically was the first data that gets pushed to the last. So all the post card is showing the same data, even though the content of the posts actually differs one from another.

What I expect after five clicks on the button:

```
[ Add new random post ]
1580789378
1580789373
1580789363
1580789349
1580789332
```

What I get:

```
[ Add new random post ]
1580789332
1580789332
1580789332
1580789332
1580789332
```

Comment: can you post the code you have?

Comment: do you have a method to call to refresh your listview?

Comment: @Qonvex620 isn't refreshing listview is by calling setState so that it triggers the whole tree to rebuild itself? If there are any way to manually recall the ListView and force it to refresh regardless of its children (e.g. by supplying key to ListView and call its "force refresh" method somewhere), I don't know and don't have it then.

Comment: Try using didUpdateWidget method the Stateful widget.

Comment: @AmitJangid oh okay, let me browse about that. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
List your_data_container;
_yourDeleteMethod()async{
  *your way of deleting*
  if(response.statuscode == 200){
    _fetchListContent();
  }
}
_yourUpdateMethod()async{
  *your way of Updating*
  if(response.statuscode == 200){
    _fetchListContent();
  }
}
_fetchListContent()async{
  *your way of fetching*
  if(response.statuscode==200){
    fetched_data = json.decode(response.body);
    setState((){
      your_data_container = *fetched_data*;
    })
  }
}
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: your_data_container.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
  return Container(
    width: screenWidth,
    height: screenHeight/15,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Text(index.toString)
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red)
          onPressed: (){
            _yourDeleteMethod();

          }
        ),
        IconButton(`
          icon: Icon(Icons.edit)
          onPressed: (){
            _yourUpdateMethod();
          }
        )
      ]
    )
  );
}
)
```

NOTE: ListView.builder should be inside build or as a widget, this is just to give you an idea this is not the whole code

Comment: I suppose I should provide my code for context from the beginning. The problem is, the itemBuilder is not returning a tree like that (which I understand that this kind of tree can refresh normally), but instead returning another Stateful Widget of mine which will not be updated when its parent tree is updated. I'm in the middle of adding the simplified code for context.